# Does a hardware wallet always generate the same seed phrase?

Tags: security, encryption, recovery, bip39, hardware-wallets

If I buy a new Ledger out of the box (untampered by the seller) and generate its seed phrase (Attempt #1), but then format the device to factory settings in order to once again re-generate a seed phrase (Attempt #2), will both of these recovery attempts generate the exact same seed phrase for that specific device?

In other words, do Ledgers have a deterministic seed phrase hard-coded in them from inception?

Answer (score 2):

From official documentation: https://www.thecryptomerchant.com/blogs/resources/hardware-wallet-recovery-seeds-explained

- Your hardware wallet can generate an unlimited number of recovery
  seeds. Every time you reset or wipe the device and then initialize
  the hardware wallet as a new device, a new sequence of 12, 18 or 24
  words will be generated. If your recovery seed gets compromised, then
  you can create a new recovery seed

Comment: ok, so if you order a hardware wallet from Amazon, you can guarantee in your mind that it wasn't tampered with by the seller if: it asks you to generate a seed phrase? This prompt for sure means the seed phrase you're about to generate could not have been already generated (and recorded by the seller and then cleared) before the device was shipped to you?

Comment: If the wallet has not been tampered with. But there were cases of Leger wallets bought from third parties that were compromised in a way you described.  I would still never use a second-hand Ledger wallet.

Comment: Do you have a source

Comment: Yeah, there was a number of articels about it. https://www.coindesk.com/tech/2021/06/17/scammers-are-sending-ledger-users-fake-hardware-wallets/

Comment: That article is post-2020 and were unsolicited shipments, not orders, whereas a Ledger ordered on Amazon in 2017 should be safe, given that the scam in the article involved the user typing in their existing seed phrase, not generating a new one.

Comment: Yeah, but there were also cases where people would order the Ledger wallet, and scammers would send them a fake/compromised one. This was just one article, but there is no shortage of scams.  The world of crypto is crazy and not short of bad actors. Always worth being careful (If you are handling serious funds)

Comment: if you order a hardware wallet from Amazon, you can guarantee in your mind that it wasn't tampered with by the seller if: it asks you to generate a seed phrase: This prompt for sure means the seed phrase you're about to generate could not have been already generated (and recorded by the seller and then cleared) before the device was shipped to you

Comment: Nice, good to know. My point was not to use second-hand wallets.  As they might be compromised.

Comment: The point here is determing whether they *are* compromised based on whether or not the device asks you to generate, rather than type in, a seed phrase. All your comments makes the assumption they are compromised by default without any sanity checks whatsoever.